# Itertool Cycle function to access the first value only once in tuple

Tags: python, iterator, tuples, python-itertools, cycle

I want to add the first value in a tuple to a list which is something like this `t=((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8))`

I want to use `cycle` function (some question) to access the first value of tuple i.e. `t[0]` to store in a list i.e equivalent to this:

```
list1=[]
list1.append(t[0])
```

How can I use `cycle` (if one has to) to cycle through the tuple `t` to store the first indexed value in `list1`?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: The `cycle` function from `itertools` is a infinite iterator.  So, if you only want one pass (which seems the case from your question), then `cycle` is not the correct tool.  Cycle is useful for operations that require infinite repetition.  An example would be a round-robin algorithm used in DNS lookup.

Comment: @Nagendra SO is a Q&A platform.  Your history shows `10` questions asked: _none_ of them have an accepted answer, and aside from `1` question that has a score of `1`, the rest are between `-5` and `0`.  This shows that your past questions were not well-received.  Also, it suggests that you do not follow up on the very questions that you posed to community.  This, to me, seems unbalanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Slurp all elements from an iterable

You can use [extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
t=((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8))
lst = []

lst.extend(t[0])  # takes an iterable
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

### Append an element from every indexed tuple

If you wanted to append only the first index of every entry in the tuple `t`:

```
t=((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8))
lst = [_t[0] for _t in t]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[1, 5]
```